# Not able to read from Parquet Reader along with Hadoop configuration using Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, hadoop, inputstream, parquet

I need to read parquet file from s3 using java & maven support.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        Path path = new Path("s3", "batch-dev", "/aman/part-e52b.c000.snappy.parquet");
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", "xxx");
        conf.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", "xxxxx");
        InputFile file = HadoopInputFile.fromPath(path, conf);
        ParquetFileReader reader2 = ParquetFileReader.open(conf, path);
        
        //MessageType schema = reader2.getFooter().getFileMetaData().getSchema();
        //System.out.println(schema);
}
```

Using above code, give FileNotFoundException

**Note that:** Note that I am using s3 scheme and not s3a. Not sure whether we have support for s3 scheme in Hadoop.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: s3://batch-dev/aman/part-e52b.c000.snappy.parquet: No such file or directory.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem.getFileStatus(S3FileSystem.java:334)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopInputFile.fromPath(HadoopInputFile.java:39)
    at com.bidgely.cloud.core.cass.gb.S3GBRawDataHandler.main(S3GBRawDataHandler.java:505)
```

However, with the same path if I use s3Client, I am able to get the object. But the problem here is that I can not read parquet data from input stream getting from below code.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("XXXXX", "XXXXX");
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("us-west-2").withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).build();
        S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("batch-dev", "/aman/part-e52b.c000.snappy.parquet"));
        System.out.println(object.getObjectContent());
}
```

Kindly help me with the solution. [I had to use java only].

Comment: Why use the HDFS client directly? You could use Hive or Spark if trying to read many files at once. And `getObjectContent` returns a stream. Parquet is binary, so where exactly are you trying to parse the binary content in your second code?

Comment: @OneCricketeer This is legacy project based on spring boot. I had to use Java. Also, I could not find a way to parse the parquet binary content. Is there any library out there using which I can read the parquet files present in s3.

Comment: Spark and Hive can read Parquet files from S3 and can be used from Java, which is why I suggested them. Alternatively, your first code block should probably use `new Path("s3://batch-dev/aman/part-e52b.c000.snappy.parquet")`, although, `s3a://` would be better

Comment: @OneCricketeer, the reason why I can not use spark is because of the deployment server. I do not have control on that and if I use spark, the server needs to be changed to execute the spark code. Any solution using java and related library would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to "install Spark", though. If you're using Maven/Gradle, you can add `spark-sql` dependency directly to your code and deploy on master=local. Or like I said, did you try using the other Path constructor to fix your file not found error?